# I need to find the longest string of ALL cells in a table

Tags: table, string

I need to find the longest string of ALL cells in a table.
Unfortunately, the table can have varying number of fields each time.
This need to be a generic function. Any leads please?

Comment: What software do you have available? This is doable with python scripts...

Comment: Are there only text and numeric fields? If you have BLOBs, like geometry, you need to specify the criteria for the BLOB's lenght

Comment: Thanks. I posted my question on another forum  with more specifics: https://geonet.esri.com/message/400009#400009

Comment: Please tell us what a "cell" is and what constitutes a "string" of them.  (One can imagine quite a few reasonable definitions in this context, so some clarification is needed.)

Comment: With respect, it's not very considerate to ask us to go read another forum to get details on your problem. Not only is it more difficult to examine the Question, but if the Esri forums ever go offline or change their URLs around, the information is lost and anyone who's got a similar question in future can't follow up. Can you please bring your information into this forum (if you still want an answer from here, too)?

Comment: whuber - For the "cell" I used Excel's terminology, meaning a single square in a table. String is a character string, or if there is a number in that cell, then it's converted to a string.

Comment: Erica, my apologies. And thanks for the continued interest.

Comment: I'm working on a labeling function in ArcGIS Desktop. The data come from a SQL Server DB, where I have no control. The tables are different every time, as the number and name of fields. it is going to be a "sub" function for the FindLabel function. I need it for calculating a number of empty spaces in a label, which depends on the max number of characters, etc. It's all to make multi-row labels nicely justified, regardless of varying nature of data that go into labels.

Answer (score 2):

pseudo code for the function is this:

```
 longestString = ""
 for each row in rows
   for each field in fields
     if length (current cell value) > length (longestString) then
        longestString = current cell value
```

How you code it depends on what software you are using.

Comment: Thanks. I posted my question on another forum  with more specifics: https://geonet.esri.com/message/400009#400009